# How to prove that the electric field strength in the interlayer is radial?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

This is a structure modified from a typical metal spherical capacitor: half of the interlayer is now filled with one kind of uniform, isotropic, and linear dielectric medium whose dielectric constant is $\epsilon$. See below:[image]
Given the radii of the ball inside and the exterior shell, now I have to calculate the capacity of this modified capacitor. My approach is that, as I use when calculating other capacities, let the ball be charged with positive charge $Q$, then calculate the electric field strength distribution in the interlayer, and finally calculate the integral $$\int_{\vec{R_1}}^{\vec{R_2}}\vec{E}(\vec{r})\centerdot d\vec{r}$$
to obtain the voltage decrease from the "anode" to the "cathode". Usually I will apply Gauss Theorem to a properly-selected close surface and work out the distribution (to be honest, maybe that's the only thing I can do to solve such problems). It is very easy but always depends terribly on the symmetry.
Now I am stuck here. The yellow sector is the Gaussian surface I selected, concentric with the ball and with a tiny solid angle $d\Omega$ as is illustrated in my drawing. Now if I know that the electric strength in the interlayer, then the only thing I need to do is to calculate the  $\vec{E}$ flux through the "bottom" and the "top" excluding the laterals, which is the key to the success of the application of Gauss Theorem here. But the prerequisite is that in the interlayer the field strength has only radial component, say, without tangent component. Were it not for the dielectric medium that breaks the symmetry this part would be just self-evident. But since the medium is here now, does it hold that the field strength is still radial and Gauss Theorem is still usable here? I believe yes, because the result is indeed rather simple and falls just within my expectation based on Gauss Theorem:
$$C=\frac{2\pi (1+\epsilon) R_1 R_2}{R_2-R_1}$$ 
But I just can't explain why. Or, perhaps the electric field strength is no longer  radial in this case (but I deem it much less possible), then with what  else can we obtain the result?

Comment: Do you know about electric displacement ?

Comment: @Vim , Hi! As far as I know, the electric field in a plane capacitor is no more a constant field toward the borders of the capacitor plates, where the field lines are curved outwards. So I expect to be the situation with your capacitor. In the middle, the field lines will be radial because of the symmetry, but not toward the borders.

Comment: @Paul Know some basic concepts and properties, but not very much. I think on the interface between the ball and the medium the Gauss Theorem for $\vec{D}$ is usable to calculate $\vec{E}$ here (which is of course radial **here**). But I don't know how to apply it for $\vec{E}$ that is **in the middle of** the medium.

Comment: @Sofia I also suspect that $\vec{E}$ will not be that simple since the symmetry has been broken. So if not in the middle, I have, thus far, no reason to deny that $\vec{E}$ are of no tangent component. And your mentioning the border effect in the case of the plane capacitor really adds to my confidence in believing that $\vec{E}$ DOES  HAVE tangent component, except in the "middle" (along the symmetry axis) or extremely near the surfaces of the ball or the shell where $\vec{E}$ must be perpendicular to the conducting surfaces.

Comment: @Sofia But if $\vec{E}$ is of tangent component, then it becomes almost impossible to calculate $U$ by integrating $\vec{E}$. Is there any other method than this one to work $U$ out?

Comment: @Vim : I didn't understand what the exercise requires you to prove? Does it require to prove the formula that you mentioned (i.e. $C = \frac {2 \pi (1 + \epsilon) R_1 R_2}{R_2 - R_1}$ ? You tell me fist what you have to prove.

Comment: @Sofia In fact the ultimate goal is to prove $C$ 's formula. I'm not meaning we have to prove $\vec{E}$ is radial, it's just a guess that I hazard, under which $C$'s calculation is easy. And this hypothesis may well be proved wrong. So, the matter is:(1) prove the hypothesis right if we can.(2) when proving it right is impossible, find an alternative method to calculate $C$.

Comment: @Vim , I see. But it's late in my country now. Let's talk tomorrow.

Comment: @Vim : no problem, however, tomorrow. It is too much late in my country.